# SQS queue stopped receiving messages for one day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We have a standard SQS queue(required permissions were set) and it stopped receiving messages 4 weeks ago and I'm trying to investigate the issue but not sure how to find out the exact reason.
Please help!!

Comment: What happens when you try to put a message to that queue? Any errors, symptoms? Your question is way broad.

Comment: What happens if you use the awscli to send a message to this queue (using 'aws sqs send_message ...').

Comment: Access denied while trying to send through AWS CLI @jarmod

Comment: @vahdet I have noticed few days ago that the queue didn't receive messages in February 3rd and trying to investigate it now.

Comment: Does the IAM policy associated with your IAM credentials actually allow sqs:SendMessage against this SQS queue (or all SQS queues)?

Comment: This is way too broad as-is - need more info to be helpful beyond a basic "It sounds like somebody made a change to your system on that date, and you need to rollback the change." It's not that the queue "isn't receiving messages", it's that the process that normally sends you messages is probably broken. Figure out why that process isn't doing what it's supposed to (error message? host died? other?) and ask THAT question if you're stuck.